# Extract time frames from days

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a computer programmer, and I like to performe some maths and I am not sure for the correct method to use.

More specific, I am creating an application that charge a client based on time usage of a service. The problem is that the services can have double charge for a pre-specified time period of the day.

So let's say we have a service for printing documents and I like to charge the printer for 5€ per hour but I like to charge the printer for 10€ between 23:00 and 02:00 the morning.

Also a client can rent the printer for as match hours he is like. This can be from 1 minute to months or even years.

Now the specific problem:

Lets say a client comes in my office to rent the printer, and he needs the printer for 55 Hours. Also the rent starts at 20:00 at night.

So tha charge must be for 43 hours in a single charge and for 12 hours in double charge. Also in the example image that following I have another two examples that describes this example better as well I have add another two, more simple examples:

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtV1W.jpg)
[image]

Now, let me give you some extra info about the hours. In programming, each hour has a timestamp that it is time passed from January 1, 1970 00:00:00 to the time in seconds.

So the date **July 05 2012 11:15:40** has the timestamp **1373022940** and the date **July 05 2012 11:15:50** has the timestamp **1373022950**

In the above example lets say that the first example placed in the date May 1, 2013, so the timestamp for 23:00 will be **1367449200** and the time stamp for three days later at the 02:00 the morning is **1367546400**

**Not the qestion:**

Is there a way to exctract the time duration of the double charged hours from a time frame ? If so, what is the process ?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the timestamp for **1** "23:00" time. That's all. We call that time `eleven`. the next "02:00" is 3 hours later, that is `3 * 3600` seconds later. So we define

```
two = eleven + 3 * 3600
```

Now we abuse the fact that integer division rounds down (in most programming languages anyway. You may also want to fix the timestamp for `eleven` to be some date in the past so that all the timestamp differences is positive).

Let (note that 86400 is the number of seconds in a day)

```
firsteleven = (start_timestamp - eleven) / 86400
lasteleven = (end_timestamp - eleven) / 86400
firsttwo = (start_timestamp - two) / 86400
lasttwo = (end_timestamp - two) / 86400
```

Using that the integer division rounds down, if `firsteleven = firsttwo` this means that the starting time is **outside** the double period. Similarly if `lasteleven = lasttwo` the ending time is **outside** the double period.

If, however, `firsteleven = firsttwo + 1` then the starting time is between 23:00 and 02:00, and similarly for the ending time if `lasteleven = lasttwo + 1`.

So the `lasttwo - firsteleven` is the total number of *full* 3 hour windows during which the double rate applies. And we have to also factor in the possible partial windows at the edge. That is to say

```
partial_start = (firsteleven - firsttwo) * ((firsttwo + 1)*86400 + two - start_timestamp)
partial_end = (lasteleven - lasttwo) * (end_timestamp - eleven - lasteleven * 86400)
total_seconds = (lasttwo - firsteleven) * 3 * 3600 + partial_start + partial_end
```